# Upgrading Oracle ODBC driver from 11 to 12 causing code to fail

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, odbc

In the process of replacing our servers which involves updating the Oracle ODBC drivers from 11 to 12. We have a process that executes on these servers that calls a stored procedure. The procedure gets passed a number of items to return one result.

For some reason, when the code that runs fine on a server with the version 11 ODBC drivers is executed on a server running version 12 it produces this error

```
[Oracle][ODBC]Function sequence error." error code S1010.
```

The configuration settings for the DSN between the two servers were copied as closely as possible (there are 3 or so new options in  version 12). The database being accessed still resided on an Oracle 11 server. Other databases residing on Oracle 12 servers require the version 12 ODBC drivers. Are there subtle differences in how a stored procedure is called or executed that my need to be addressed?

I cannot post the code details for company policy reasons.

Comment: The "code" that is failing: I assume certain PL/SQL procedures or functions.  Or is it straight SQL queries that are failing?  If it is PL/SQL, are all packages/procedures/functions failing or just certain ones?  '

Comment: Sorry I took so long to reply. I can't answer that particular question as it is SQL called from within an executable. I do not have access to the code but have been working with the designer. In this case the code works when used with Oracle 11 drivers but not Oracle 12 drivers. We elected to stick to the Oracle 11 drivers until it becomes a problem.